# Jordan's Paper on the Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, linear-algebra

In which paper, did Jordan introduce/prove the Jordan canonical form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who discovered the Jordan normal form?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/who-discovered-the-jordan-normal-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Hawkins ([1977](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=528299), [§5](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133484)): 2 $\times$ 2 case in ([1868](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?01.0040.01), [pp. 111–113](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k16412q/f119)), *n* $\times$ *n* in *Traité des substitutions et des équations algébriques* ([1870](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?03.0042.02), [pp. 114–126](https://archive.org/details/traitdessubsti00jorduoft/page/114)). Also *Cours d’analyse*, vol. 3 ([1887](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?19.0252.01), [pp. 173–175](https://archive.org/details/coursdanalyspoly03jorduoft/page/173)).